# In Java how can I get a subsequence of number string whose indices can be as 10^5 digits long

Tags: java, biginteger, subsequence

In Java how can I get a subsequence of BigInteger whose indices can be   10^5  digits long.

Example : BigInteger length is 10^5 .
I have to find subsequence between index 10^3 and 10^4

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried the `substring(int, int)` method?

Comment: Yes , it does not work as substring takes int as arguments , but in my case they are bigIntegers

Comment: `new String(new char[100000]).substring(1000, 10000)`

Comment: @user2418640 A `String` is backed by a `char[]`, and an array cannot have more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, so indexes cannot exceed the range of `int`, ergo there is no need for index to be `BigInteger`.

Comment: @Andreas you are correct . I have update the question . Please check now .

Comment: A `BigInteger` doesn't have "indices" or "subsequences", so it's unclear what it is you want. Are you saying that if the `BigInteger` has the value `12345678` and you want subsequence between index 1 (inclusive) and index 4 (exclusive), that means a new number with value `567`? or `234`? or what?

Comment: @Andreas Yes you are correct.

Comment: I like being correct, but since I listed 3 mutually exclusive choices, I still don't know what I was correct about. Update your question and clarify what it is you wanted, e.g. with an example like I gave.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String yourSubstring = Str.substring(9999, 10000);
```

This is will give you the string from 10^3 to 10^4.

To convert a BigInt to String you can use:

```
String str = yourBigInt.toString();
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, can you please add an explanation?

Comment: Yup!  The endpoint of `Str.substring(begin,end)` is *exclusive*.  And FYI, I will remove my DV when you fix your answer.

Comment: @intboolstring Ok. Got you. Updated the code. I guess this is what he wanted

Comment: the index can have 10^3 "digits"  not the number 1000 . Also have updated the question based on Andreas comment

Comment: @user2418640 yes, then you convert that number to String and then use the above function

Comment: @PritamBanerjee The BigInt can have 10^3 digits means 1000 Digits, so like this: 123123123123....(digit 10^3).

Answer (score 0):

Study this code and see if it solves your question. If it doesn't, maybe you will find some information within that will help.

```
public class TestBigInteger 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String makeNumber = "";
        int numberOfDigits = 10000;
        String newNumberString = "";
        Random random = new Random();
        BigInteger result;


        for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; i++ ) {
            makeNumber += random.nextInt( 9 );
        }
        newNumberString = makeNumber.substring( 100, 999);
        result = new BigInteger( newNumberString );

    }

}
```